# What does たら do at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, ellipsis

> 時間があるなら、彼の画廊に寄ってみ**たら。**

What meaning does たら have at the end of a sentence?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 時間があるなら、彼の画廊に寄ってみ**たら**。
> If you have time, *why don't you* drop by his art gallery?

When used at the end of a sentence, and usually with a rising tone, たら indicates a **suggestion, recommendation or advice**, meaning *"Why don't you ~~?" "You should ~~" "How about ~~?"* You can think of it as the shortened form of 「～たらどう？」 or 「～たらどうですか？」

たら is the 仮定形 (hypothetical form) of the auxiliary た. See definition #8 of the 助動詞 "た" in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/132183/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9F/):

> ８ （「…たらどうか」「…たらいかがでしょうか」などの形で）**助言したり提案したり勧誘したり**する場合に用いられる。「この件は継続審議ということにしたらいかがでしょうか」
> [補説]... 仮定形「たら」は、多く「ば」を伴わないで「雨が降ったら中止だ」などと使われ、**「遅いからもう帰ったら」のように文末に用いられて**8の意を表す。

Answer (score 4):

A verb + a postpositional particle  "たら" is used when you suggest something.