# question about ったら and どうするんだろう

Tags: translation, hiragana

I am trying to read ぼのぼの vol 1, where the very first page of the comic has this:

[image]

I managed to translate it to:

```
森は楽しい
森は楽しい
水の音聞こえる
水の音聞こえる
ハナをかむ音も聞こえる
ハナをかむ音は
どうするんだろう
__からどうするんだろう
森は楽しい
森は楽しいったら

The forest is fun
The forest is fun
You can hear the sound of water
You can hear the sound of water
You can also hear the sound of a nose being blown
I wonder What we can about the sound of a nose being blown
What will we do about it ?
The forest is fun
The forest could be fun
```

But I can't work out what the characters before the second `どうするんだろう` are meant to be. I was thinking `これから`, but it is not very clear. Does anyone have any idea what this might say?

Also unsure about the last line `森は楽しいったら`. I read that `たら` is conditional/hypothetical form, but not sure how that makes sense here unless it reads `the forest **could be** fun` or just `**if** the forest is fun`, but the latter doesn't seem to make much sense.

Any general feedback is also very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it reads これから. The second stroke of れ, わ and ね is sometimes handwritten like this, although it can look childish or comic-like. You can see れ similar to this in some comic-style fonts, too.
2. This (っ)たら is a sentence-end particle for emphasis. In this case, its meaning is something like "yes", "it really is", "I mean it" or "that's for sure". It's often used when the speaker is mildly irritated, like "hey", "come on" or "are you listening?", "believe me", etc.

   > #### [たら](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139153/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89/)
   >
   > ［終助］《係助詞「たら」の文末用法から》名詞、活用語の終止形・命令形に付く。
   >   １ じれったいという気持ちを込めて相手に促す意を表す。「ねえ、おとうさんたら」
   >   ２ 驚き・いらだちなどの気持ちを表す。「まあ、あなたったら」「いいかげんにしろったら」

   たら at the end of a sentence [can be a suggestion, too](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29766/5010) (in this case たら is conditional).